# How do I monitor bandwidth use of specific websites?

Tags: network

I'm using Chrome on SnowLeopard.  I use the www a lot.  I want to monitor how much bandwidth I use for all SE sites in one month.  I don't care how much bandwidth is used on any other website.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Best answer will be an accurate tool to measure; but a reasonable estimate is acceptable too.

Comment: How comfortable to you feel regarding reconfiguring Apache to run as a proxy (as well as a web server)?

Comment: A good place to start looking would be firewall logging.  An enabled firewall and some correctly crafted rules plus logging would do what you want.  I've seen  iptables used in this manner on Linux. I know that MacOS has ipfw. BTW, a firewall know *exactly* how many bytes were transferred over a connection.

Answer (score 1):

[Historygram](http://www.signifierstudio.com/historygram/) is a neat extension for Safari, but it appears to only measure visits, not bandwidth. Feel free to email the author and ask if this extension could easily be modified to include bandwidth measurement.